# For loop variable is empty in gmake

Tags: gnu-make

I have a list of header files created thus:

```
expand=$(1)/$(1).h
HDRS=$(foreach x, $(DIRS), $(call expand,$(x)))
```

Which yields a list like a/a.h b/b.h ...

but when I use this in a for loop:

```
for i in $(HDRS) ; do \
    echo $$i \
    cp $$i $(some_dir) \
done
```

$$i is empty. And the cp fails, having only one argument.

The usual variants of $$i ( $i, $$i, $(i), ${i} ), don't change anything, nor do the usual variants of $(HDRS) ("$(HDRS)", etc.).

gmake echos the for-loop as

```
for i in a.h b.h ; \
do \
    echo $i \
    cp $i somedir \
done
```

Which looks correct.

But the implicit bash shell emits an error "/bin/sh -c: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

gmake then exits due to the failed command.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you showed us the actual output you see, if any.

Comment: @MadScientist: Added the output.

Comment: It shows that error because (as pointed out below) without the semicolons, the cp and `done` keywords are passed to echo as arguments rather than being interpreted as shell keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the `\`, make emits the recipe as a single line.  This confuses the shell.  Try this instead, using `;` in place of the line terminator:

```
for i in a.h b.h ; \
do \
    echo $i ; \
    cp $i somedir ; \
done
```

Comment: That worked. I assumed the problem was the variable, and never checked the shell invocation. Oops.